# Dyadic approach to Marcinkiewicz interpolation for Lorentz Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

In Exercise 21 , in a note for professor Terrence Tao on his own blog

http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/

> **Exercise 21** Suppose we are in the situation of the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem, with the hypotheses $p_0\le q_0$, $p_1\le q_1$ replaced by $p_0\ne p_1$. Show that for all $0\lt\theta\lt1$, and $1\leq r \leq \infty$ there exits a $B\gt0$ such that
>   $$
> \|Tf\|_{L^{\large q_\theta,r}(Y)} \leq B \|f\|_{L^{\large p_\theta , r }(X)}
> $$
>   for all simple functions $f$ of finite measure support, where the Lorentz norms $L^{p,q}$ were defined in Exercise 7. (Hint: repeat the proof of the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem, but partition the sum $\sum_{n,m}$ into regions of the form $\{n\alpha q_\theta-mp_\theta=k+O(1)\}$ for integer $k$. Obtain a bound for each summand which decreases geometrically as $k\to\pm\infty$.) Conclude that the hypotheses $p_0\le q_0$, $p_1\le q_1$ in the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem can be replaced by $p_\theta\le q_\theta$. This Lorentz space version of the interpolation theorem is in some sense the “right” version of the theorem, but the Lorentz spaces are slightly more technical to deal with than the Lebesgue spaces, and the Lebesgue space version of Marcinkiewicz interpolation is largely sufficient for most applications.

I can see how to approach it using duality between $L^{q,r}$ and $L^{q',r'}$ in case that $q_{\theta} > 1$ , but I want to know also how to approach it using tao approach sketched in a comment in the same note where he introduced a frequency envelope.The following is the comment ( I suggest reading his proof of marinkiewicz )

> ah, yes, this is a little delicate, in part because the decomposition of f used here is actually not the optimal one for this problem – it decomposes the height  of the function dyadically (vertical dyadic decomposition), when in fact it is the width  that ought to be dyadically decomposed (horizontal dyadic decomposition). One can still recover from this point by decomposing the sequence  into dyadic pieces, but this is quite messy.Another approach is to use frequency envelopes. Pick a small $\epsilon$ and replace $a_ m $ by the slightly larger envelope $ b_m : = \sup_{m'} 2^{\epsilon |m-m'|} a_{m'}$ ' The point of doing so is that the $b_m $ obey a Lipschitz property $2^{-\epsilon |m-m'|} b_{m'} \leq b_m \leq 2^{\epsilon |m-m'|} b_{m'} $ but are still summable in $l^1$ . One then chooses $c_{n,m}$  to be adapted to the crossover point between the two quantities in the $\min $ (modifying the $n \alpha q_{\theta} - m p_{\theta} $  term by some multiple of $\log b_m$ ); as long as the Lipschitz parameter $\epsilon$  is small enough, one will still be able to close the argument

I only want to see how frequency envelopes work .

Thanks

Comment: I find Marcinkiewicz interpolation to be very hard and messy.  There is a different approach using the so called Boyd indices.  I wrote a paper about it: http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/hardy.html but I must admit that I didn't fill in the blanks.  But from this you can get the Marcinkiewicz interpolation for Lorentz Spaces.  I would be glad to explain this further to you if you like.

Comment: Thanks , I will read he paper as soon as I finish my study for the theory of hardy operators ,  and other things which are preassumed in the paper .... still curious to know how tao's approach works.